# Why spring security config shouldn't be used directly in applications?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Why the description on [org.springframework.security.config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/package-summary.html) say that "None of the code in these packages should be used directly in applications." ?

On [(baeldung)spring-security-with-maven](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-with-maven) they say to use 
`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    **<scope>runtime</scope>**
</dependency>
```

`

But in my app I need compile scope...

Comment: As Baeldung writes in his tutorial: `No application code should compile against this dependency`. So why do you need it as a compile scope dependency?

Answer (score 1):

By saying

> "None of the code in these packages should be used directly in
>   applications."

they mean to say:

> "do not call the methods or use classes in this package directly in your code"

Comment: annotations included ?